# Opposite action of os.startfile

Tags: python, operating-system

I am using python to refresh a special command in the excel that it will only got refreshed when I open the excel file and display in the monitor (cannot use with open / other methods, from my current understanding).

So I try to use os.startfile to open it and it did beautifully. But now, as I still need to use other data in the excel and I need to close the excel file by doing an opposite action of os.startfile. May I ask is there such a command? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import os
from time import sleep
os.startfile('yourFile.xclx')
sleep(4)
os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM EXCEL.EXE')
# os.system('TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE yourtitle"')
```

[link to the source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJm9m8kv7gU)

Comment: module 'os' has no attribute 'openfile'

Comment: Also, if I change the os.openfile to os.startfile and run it, this program will kill all the excel files instead of just the one I opened. Is there an alternative to close just the one I opened?

Comment: os has attribute startfile noticed my mistake

Comment: if you checked the source he explains it would kill all

Comment: but you can look up more info about taskkill in cmd

Comment: type: taskkill /? in cmd

Comment: as I see you would need to get PID of a task and taskkill by PID but again for more info take a look at taskkill /? in cmd